# Copying failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, exit-code, copying

Somehow an image in my project became missing after moving it throughout the project. So, I delete the png image in question but I am unable to run my app using the simulator but end up with this obnoxious error.

[image: Copying Error]

I've thus deleted the image in question from my computer, aside from its current location in my project and deleted the derived data using the terminal. However, the issue is still appearing. Unsure what to try next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler wants to copy the image from the Downloads folder (pretty weird location by the way ) into the bundle while building the app.

If you need to use the image delete it from the project, add it again and check `Copy Items if needed`.

Otherwise remove the image from Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: Yep, just got to that, haha! Thanks. You're the winner of the check but I also wanted to post this link as this describes this issue a bit more!.  http://lukagabric.com/ios-copypng-failed-with-exit-code-1/